# scp recursive upload is incomplete

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, backup, scp

I want to transmit with scp a folder and it's contents, including subdirectories. The size of the directory is `16.2GB` and it contains `40.647` files and `7.463` subdirectories. The local machine runs Windows 10, the remote machine runs Lubuntu.

I have tried running the commands `scp -r "D:/Projekts" backup:/home/lars/backup`, `scp -r "D:/Projekts/." backup:/home/lars/backup` and `scp -r "D:/Projekts/*" backup:/home/lars/backup`. The second command with the dot didn't execute due to file not found. I've also tried PowerShell and CMD.

After the command (*first or third*) executed, part of the directory has been uploaded.

The size of the folder structure, being uploaded with: `scp -r "D:/Projekts/*" backup:/home/lars/backup` is `9.9GB`, and contains `9737` Files. Looking in the contents of the folder structure, you can see, that the uploaded subdirectories got uploaded completely, starting in alphabetic order. There are just a couple subdirectories missing.

The size of the other folder structure is `2.4GB` with `2262` Files. The contents of this folder structure is the same, with the difference that fewer subdirectories got uploaded.

Looking at the facts, it would be plausible, that scp somehow limits the files you can upload at once, because the subdirectories, which weren't uploaded could be uploaded, when explicitly uploading these subdirectories.

What could be possible solutions to upload the whole directory?

Comment: What folders you are missing in the destination? Can you grab the output for the command?

Comment: I did that, and according to the logs, there has been an exit status 1.
This was right after an empty file. That means scp probably crashes on transmitting an empty file. 
I sadly haven't found a method to either ignore and resume after errors or to transmit empty files. I've tried using compression `scp -r -C "D:/Projekts/*" "backup:/home/lars/backup/projects"`, but this sadly didn't work and crashed at the same place.

Answer (score 2):

`scp` is a great tool, but for large collections of files, I reccomend you try `rsync`.  `rsync` will operate over `ssh`, so you should need no more configuration on your system, other than perhaps getting a version of `rsync` that will work for your platform/OS - Windows, I'm guessing.

The form of the command line will be something like this:

```
rsync -az "D:/Projekts/" backup:/home/lars/backupp/
```

... though I am not an active windows user, so you'll have to make sure the paths work for Windows.

One note of importance - the trailing slash (`/`) has meaning, so you should read the man page for `rsync`.  There are lots of other options as well that may help you accomplish your goals.  The most notable of which is probably `--delete`, which deletes files on the destination that are not or no-longer present on the source.

In the event of an interruption, either networking or anything else, you can re-issue the same rsync command and it will figure out only the files that need to be (re-)transmitted.